# How can I expand macros and write the expansion to an external file?

Tags: expansion, external-files, expl3

I'm trying to do a bit of single-sourcing with my resume, and would like to write given information to an external text file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { resume/contact } {
  street   .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_street_tl,
  street   .initial:n = {default ~ street},
  city     .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_city_tl,
  city     .initial:n = {default ~ city},
  state    .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_state_tl,
  state    .initial:n = {default ~ state},
  zip      .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_zip_tl,
  zip      .initial:n = {default ~ zip},
  name     .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_name_tl,
  name     .initial:n = {default ~ name},
  phone    .tl_set:N  = \l_resume_contact_phone_tl,
  phone    .initial:n = {default ~ phone},
}

\iow_new:N \bcv_iow
\NewDocumentCommand \ContactInformation { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { resume / contact } { #1 }

  \iow_open:Nn \bcv_iow { \jobname.bcv.txt }
  \iow_now:Nn  \bcv_iow
  {
    ~~~~~~~ ~~~Name:~ \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_name_tl    \\
    Street~ Address:~ \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_street_tl  \\
    ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~:~ \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_city_tl    ,~
                      \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_state_tl   ,~
                      \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_zip_tl     \\
    ~~~~~~~ ~~Phone:~ \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_phone_tl   \\
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ContactInformation{
  name   = (name),
  street = (123 Main St.),
  city   = (city),
  state  = (state),
  zip    = (zip),
  phone  = (phone),
}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

which produces the following in `*.bcv.txt`:

```
Name: \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_name_tl \\Street Address: \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_street_tl \\: \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_city_tl , \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_state_tl , \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_zip_tl \\Phone: \tl_use:N \l_resume_contact_phone_tl \\
```

where I would expect something like:

```
          Name: (name)
Street Address: (123 Main St.), (city), (state), (zip)
         Phone: (phone)
```

Obviously, the macros set by `l3keys` are not being expanded in the file write.
How achieve the desired result?

Comment: You should also use a group around your replacement text of `\ContactInformation` or the initial values will be wept out at the first call of `\keys_set:nn`.

Comment: @egreg that is more or less intended behavior. I know that this is normally done, but I couldn't think of a case where I'd want to return to the defaults. Am I missing an entire category of functionality?

Comment: Then you don't need `.initial`, but rather a test that the value has been given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour of `\iow_now:Nn` is detailed in the `expl3` documentation:

> This functions writes ⟨tokens⟩ to the specified ⟨stream⟩ immediately

Thus what you see is entirely as expected: you are writing the tokens themselves. Thus if you wish to write the expansion of the tokens you should be using normal `expl3` expansion variants: `\iow_now:Nx` (defined as standard).

As well as expansion, you also need to be careful about the material inside the write operation. The LaTeX `\\` command creates a new line in typeset output: it does not create a new line in a written file (at least in general). Instead, you should either use `\iow_newline:` or carry out separate write operations for each line. (We do allow `\\` to be used with `\iow_wrap:Nnnn`: the behaviour here may need some minor improvements.)

As TeX ignores spaces at the start of lines, all of your `~` are ineffective and you will need to use `\c_space_tl` to make 'pretty' alignments.

Comment: Maybe `\exp_not:V` instead of `\tl_use:N`?

Comment: @egreg Probably most sensible as we are inside an `x`-type expansion, yes

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I think I'm finally starting to understand expl3's expansion control.  I had been using the `x` variant, but my use of ``\\`` (indeed suggested by `\iow_wrap:…`) was probably causing it to trip up (something about `\reserved@?` undefined).  Thanks again!

Comment: @SeanAllred The LaTeX2e definition of ``\\`` isn't protected, so inside an `x`-type expansion 'explodes'. As I said, perhaps we need to look at this again (it is a useful shortcut): I'll raise with the team.